# Is it possible to create a native Universal Windows Application using Vue and/or Angular?

Tags: vue.js, uwp

If it is possible, what is a good starting point? I've done native app development with Angular and Electron, but I like the idea of leveraging the features and capabilities of the UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can build native UWP apps using JavaScript, as it is one of the languages WinRT supports out of the box.

You can check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-uwp) for a Hello World example of a UWP JS  app and go from there.

The [UWP Sample Gallery](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) contains many samples of the APIs you have available and most of them contain a `js` folder which contains the JavaScript version of the sample, so this is a great source of where you can learn. The Windows APIs are available through the `Windows` "namespace".

You can include any framework you want in the app, you just put it into your package and you are goot to go.

Comment: Is any documentation available, How to use Angular to develop UWP application.I Followed the below video link but it not clearly explained.https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/JavaScript-Webinar-Series/Building-a-Universal-Windows-Platform-app-using-Angular/Building-a-Universal-Windows-Platform-app-using-Angular